# Getting website descriptions

Tags: php

I'm trying to pull various data from a supplied url, including the description meta information using this:-

```
$tags = get_meta_tags($_POST['url']);
echo $tags['description'];
```

This works fine for some sites, but not all.  For example, if I try http://twitter.com I get nothing, but a google search (or entering the url into facebook) reveals the following text:-

> Instantly connect to what's most important to you. Follow your friends, experts, favorite celebrities, and breaking news.

This text doesn't exist in the source of the twitter page - where does this come from, and how would I get hold of it?  Similarly, my code returns nothing for http://bbc.com either.

Comment: The meta description seems to exists in the cached page google has: [link](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:54wUqjYXkAkJ:https://twitter.com/&hl=en&gl=ar&strip=0).

Comment: If I go to twitter and then view source, I don't see the meta description.  What am I missing?

Comment: Well I mean... sorry Mat. Your problem can't be solved. If twitter is serving up some HTML to you that is different from what the rest of us are seeing and *doesn't have the meta description*, then you *can't get the meta description*. It's that simple.

Comment: But the problem has been solved, or wouldn't work on sites like Facebook/google plus when you type in a url and it pulls the data automatically..  So..my question then is (as stated) - where can I get this information if not available in a meta tag?  Other sites seem to be able to access it.  How?

Comment: Will you update the question to show the `<head>` section that you see when you view the source at twitter.com? Like meager, I see the meta description here.

Comment: There's a bit too much to copy/paste as lots of in-page styling...it's definitely not there though...odd.

Comment: There's something majestically screwed up with Twitter's source. I've just been hacking away at getting it to work with a regular expression, but with `"|<meta[^>]+name=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]" . "+content=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]+>|i"` I get all meta-tags except the `description`, while I see it in the source it's parsing...

Comment: Mat, even though it is a lot, it still may help point us in the right direction. Maybe you are getting a modified version of the site from a proxy or something. If we can compare our results to yours we will have a starting point to work from. If needed, feel free to use [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) for the full dump and include just relevant snippets here.

Comment: Actually, I just logged out, and the source does display the meta content..  If I log back in, it disappears..

Comment: Yes, it shows when not logged in. I just posted an answer that probably explains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your hosted server has an IP that is not in any GeoIP database.

I just whipped together this bit of code:

```
function get_meta_tags_from_path($path)
{
    $tags = array();
    $source = file_get_contents($path);
    $count = preg_match_all(
        "|<meta[^>]+name=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]" . "+content=\"([^\"]*)|i",
        $source, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++)
        $tags[$matches[1][$i]] = $matches[2][$i];
    return $tags;
}

$tags = get_meta_tags_from_path('https://twitter.com/'));
$description = $tags['description'];
```

It works fine, as [demonstrated here](http://opbokken.nu/twitterdom.php). ***HOWEVER***, you can also see it's showing a *Dutch* meta description, as the server is located in the Netherlands, on a known Dutch IP. It could very well be that Twitter, if it cannot determine the probable locale of the visitor through `Accept-language` tag or GeoIP, will just not try to serve up localized content. You're rather out of luck then on your hosting machine, unless you use cURL to whip up a request with the proper `Accept` headers included to simulate an actual browser.

Comment: I did try a quick test using cURL and it didn't return anything, but  file_get_contents did (including the meta description).  Might just be my lack of understanding of how to use cURL though...

Comment: If `file_get_contents` does return the content with the meta description, you can use this function to achieve your result. Should actually work fine for every website you throw at it.

Comment: Yep, that was what I thought.  Just need to figure out how to get what I need from the returned data now...  I'll get there, eventually.

Comment: Just follow the last 2 lines of my code, changed them for your purposes  :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but the premise of your question is wrong:

> This text doesn't exist in the source of the twitter page

Yes it does:

> ```
> <meta name="description" content="Instantly connect to what&#39;s most important to you. Follow your friends, experts, favorite celebrities, and breaking news.">`
> ```
>
> -- twitter.com

And `var_dump(get_meta_tags("http://twitter.com"));`:

```
array(4) {
  ["description"]=>
  string(125) "Instantly connect to what&#39;s most important to you. Follow your friends, experts, favorite celebrities, and breaking news."
  ["msapplication-tileimage"]=>
  string(42) "//abs.twimg.com/favicons/win8-tile-144.png"
  ["msapplication-tilecolor"]=>
  string(7) "#00aced"
  ["swift-page-name"]=>
  string(5) "front"
}
```

Comment: If I view source in Chrome and search for the text I'm not finding it...what am I missing?  My code returns nothing for description.

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the twitter login page, not your personalized home page? Try logging our or opening an incognito window...

Comment: That wouldn't make a difference, as I'm running my php script on a hosted server.  I did try, just to confirm my suspicions, but no different output.